# Falling back on Android resource values for attribute defaults in a microformat

Tags: html, android-resources, microformats

I'm designing a microformat to be consumed by my Android client, where I extract some elements containing menu commands and other metadata before pushing the remaining content into a WebView.

I currently embed each menu command as a JSON object, like:

```
<span class="menu-command">{"type": "SHARE"}</span>
```

The handler logic is implemented natively by the client, and the display properties (title, icon) are pulled from the resource XML.

Now I'm considering switching to more semantic HTML5 tags, possibly something like:

```
<menu>
  <menuitem label="Share" data-type="SHARE">
  <!-- other actions -->
</menu>
```

with data-* attributes for any other fields required for the JSON spec (depending on the type of the action).

We'd still like to use the Android app's resource file to get default values for the command's label and icon, but I'm not sure of the most standards-friendly way to do so; the label attribute is required, and any logic to replace that value isn't to the letter of the standard, at least.

Is there any standards-compliant, or at least conventional way for a client to replace the value of an HTML attribute in this fashion?